How to clean a json file to become a Dataframe?
I am scraping basketball stats from MaxPreps (high school sports stats website). I successfully got the data into my vscode, but the json data is huge and messy. I can see all the proper numbers and player names, but it isn't in neat rows and columns. How would I go about getting the json file to be a neat rows/columns dataframe?
I tried the pandas normalizing feature but wasn't sure what I was looking at. I tried comparing the output to NBA's stat website, and their data looked more organized as if their output was the table of stats from the website.
My Code:
import pandas as pd
import requests
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
import numpy as np

test_url = 'https://production.api.maxpreps.com/gatewayweb/react/team-season-player-stats/rollup/v1?teamId=cb3c4816-4749-4381-8c4c-5613ef8c89c9&sportSeasonId=77be7c75-cdf9-483d-867f-ea2af557e731'
url_json = requests.get(url=test_url).json()


df_normal = pd.json_normalize(url_json)
print(df_normal)
#print(url_json)

  {'status': 200, 'message': 'Success', 'cacheResult': 'None', 'data': {'teamId': 'cb3c4816-4749-4381-8c4c-5613ef8c89c9', 'sportSeasonId': '77be7c75-cdf9-483d-867f-ea2af557e731', 'groups': [{'name': 'Game Stats', 'subgroups': [{'name': '', 'stats': {'columns': [{'name': 'Jersey', 'header': '#', 'displayName': '#', 'isSortedColumn': True, 'overallValue': None, 'sortDirection': 1, 'columnType': 1}, {'name': 'Name', 'header': 'Name', 'displayName': 'Name', 'isSortedColumn': False, 'overallValue': None, 'sortDirection': 0, 'columnType': 2}, {'name': 'GamesPlayed', 'header': 'GP', 'displayName': 'Games Played', 'isSortedColumn': True, 'overallValue': '29', 'sortDirection': 2, 'columnType': 0}, {'name': 'MinutesPerGame', 'header': 'MPG', 'displayName': 'Minutes Per Game', 'isSortedColumn': True, 'overallValue': '0', 'sortDirection': 2, 'columnType': 0}, {'name': 'PointsPerGame', 'header': 'PPG', 'displayName': 'Points Per Game', 'isSortedColumn': True, 'overallValue': '53.2

^^^json data
How I want it to look
parameters
: 
{LeagueID: "00", PerMode: "Totals", StatCategory: "PTS", Season: "All Time", SeasonType: "Playoffs",…}
resource
: 
"leagueleaders"
resultSet
: 
{name: "LeagueLeaders",…}
headers
: 
["PLAYER_ID", "PLAYER_NAME", "GP", "MIN", "FGM", "FGA", "FG_PCT", "FG3M", "FG3A", "FG3_PCT", "FTM",…]
name
: 
"LeagueLeaders"
rowSet
: 
[,…]
[0 … 99]
0
: 
[2544, "LeBron James", 287, 11858, 2928, 5896, 0.497, 470, 1415, 0.332, 1836, 2479, 0.741, 430, 2153,…]
1
: 
[893, "Michael Jordan", 179, 7474, 2188, 4497, 0.487, 148, 446, 0.332, 1463, 1766, 0.828, 305, 847,…]
2
: 
[76003, "Kareem Abdul-Jabbar", 237, 8851, 2356, 4422, 0.533, 0, 4, 0, 1050, 1419, 0.74, 505, 1273,…]
3
: 
[977, "Kobe Bryant", 220, 8641, 2014, 4499, 0.448, 292, 882, 0.331, 1320, 1617, 0.816, 230, 889, 1119,…]

{'resource': 'leagueleaders', 'parameters': {'LeagueID': '00', 'PerMode': 'Totals', 'StatCategory': 'PTS', 'Season': 'All Time', 'SeasonType': 'Playoffs', 'Scope': 'S', 'ActiveFlag': 'No'}, 'resultSet': {'name': 'LeagueLeaders', 'headers': ['PLAYER_ID', 'PLAYER_NAME', 'GP', 'MIN', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT_PCT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF', 'PTS', 'AST_TOV', 'STL_TOV', 'EFG_PCT', 'TS_PCT', 'GP_RANK', 'MIN_RANK', 'FGM_RANK', 'FGA_RANK', 'FG_PCT_RANK', 'FG3M_RANK', 'FG3A_RANK', 'FG3_PCT_RANK', 'FTM_RANK', 'FTA_RANK', 'FT_PCT_RANK', 'OREB_RANK', 'DREB_RANK', 'REB_RANK', 'AST_RANK', 'STL_RANK', 'BLK_RANK', 'TOV_RANK', 'PF_RANK', 'PTS_RANK', 'AST_TOV_RANK', 'STL_TOV_RANK', 'EFG_PCT1', 'TS_PCT1'], 'rowSet': [[2544, 'LeBron James', 287, 11858, 2928, 5896, 0.497, 470, 1415, 0.332, 1836, 2479, 0.741, 430, 2153, 2583, 2067, 483, 275, 1034, 655, 8162, 1.999, 0.467, 0.536, 0.584, 1, 1, 1, 1, 591, 3, 2, 714, 1, 1, 1262, 16, 1, 4, 2, 1, 10, 1, 8, 1, 469, 1078, 491, 405], [893, 'Michael Jordan', 179, 7474, 2188, 4497, 0.487, 148, 446, 0.332, 1463, 1766, 0.828, 305, 847, 1152, 1022, 376, 158, 546, 541, 5987, 1.872, 0.689, 0.503, 0.568, 19, 12, 3, 3, 65

Stats from NBA ^^^
Something similar like this was covered already, but it was using stats from NBA.com. I am not sure how it translates to the data I have from MaxPreps. I basically want to take my data MaxPreps and make it so it is in a clean data frame so I can begin graphing it.

The problem with the previous code is it's being appended instead of joined/merged.
This will do the trick:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from functools import reduce
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


test_url = 'https://production.api.maxpreps.com/gatewayweb/react/team-season-player-stats/rollup/v1?teamId=cb3c4816-4749-4381-8c4c-5613ef8c89c9&sportSeasonId=77be7c75-cdf9-483d-867f-ea2af557e731'
url_json = requests.get(url=test_url).json()

jsonData = url_json['data']
data_dict = {}
for gr in jsonData['groups']:
    row_list = []
    groupName = gr['name']
    
    subgroups = gr['subgroups']
    stats = subgroups[0]['stats']
    
    columns = [x['name'] for x in stats['columns']]
    rows = stats['rows']
    for row in rows:
        if isinstance(row['columns'], list):
            values = [x['value'] for x in row['columns']]
            rowData = dict(zip(columns, values))
            row_list.append(rowData)
        else:
            continue
        
    data_dict[groupName] = pd.DataFrame(row_list)

df_normal = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Name', 'Jersey'], how='inner', suffixes=('', '_DROP')), data_dict.values())
df_normal = df_normal.loc[:, ~df_normal.columns.str.endswith('_DROP')]

Output:
print(df_normal.to_string())
   Jersey             Name GamesPlayed MinutesPerGame PointsPerGame DefensiveReboundsPerGame OffensiveReboundsPerGame ReboundsPerGame AssistsPerGame StealsPerGame BlocksPerGame TurnoversPerGame PersonalFoulsPerGame MinutesPlayed Points FieldGoalsMade FieldGoalAttempts FieldGoalPercentage PointsPerShot AdjustedFGPercentage OffensiveRebounds DefensiveRebounds Rebounds Assists Steals BlockedShots Turnovers PersonalFouls AssistsPerTurnover StealsPerTurnover StealsPerPersonalFoul BlocksPerPersonalFoul Charges Deflections TechnicalFouls DoubleDouble TripleDouble PointsPer32 AssistsPer32 ReboundsPer32 StealsPer32 BlocksPer32 TurnoversPer32 PersonalFoulsPer32
0      24       B. Girotti          22            5.5           0.5                      0.6                      0.1             0.7            0.2           0.1             0              0.5                  0.3           121     12              5                25                  20           0.5                   24                 2                14       16       5      2            0        12             6               0.42              0.17                  0.33                     0       1           8              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
1       1        J. Nguyen          24            4.7           0.8                      0.6                      0.2             0.8            0.2           0.1           0.0              0.2                  0.4           113     19              8                18                  44           1.1                   47                 4                14       18       5      2            1         5            10               1.00              0.40                  0.20                  0.10       0           2              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
2      32       D. Dechene          22            5.1           1.2                      1.5                      0.7             2.1            0.3           0.1           0.2              0.5                  1.0           113     26             11                32                  34           0.8                   38                15                32       47       6      3            5        11            21               0.55              0.27                  0.14                  0.24       0           3              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
3       0           C. Kim          29           18.2           3.2                      0.9                      0.7             1.6            1.2           0.8           0.0              1.8                  1.3           529     92             32               109                  29           0.8                   38                19                27       46      36     22            1        51            38               0.71              0.43                  0.58                  0.03       0          31              0            0            0         5.6            0             0           0           0              0                  0
4      30          A. Phan          29           21.4           3.1                      1.4                      1.1             2.5            1.8           0.9             0              1.7                  2.1           622     89             36               144                  25           0.6                   30                32                40       73      52     26            0        48            62               1.08              0.54                  0.42                     0      18          25              0            0            0         4.6            0             0           0           0              0                  0
5      13        M. Ligman          22            4.8           0.2                      0.5                      0.2             0.8            0.3           0.1             0              0.3                  0.4           105      5              1                11                   9           0.5                   14                 5                12       17       7      2            0         6             8               1.17              0.33                  0.25                     0       0           5              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
6      12         L. Parra           4            5.5           1.3                      1.0                      0.3             1.3            0.3           0.3           0.3              0.3                    0            22      5              1                 7                  14           0.7                   14                 1                 4        5       1      1            1         1             0               1.00              1.00                     0                     0       0           1              0            0            0         7.3            0           7.3           0           0              0                  0
7       4      L. Davis iv          29           16.6           5.3                      1.7                      0.7             2.4            0.7           0.4           0.1              1.1                  0.9           480    154             60               167                  36           0.9                   44                21                50       71      19     13            3        32            26               0.59              0.41                  0.50                  0.12       1          12              0            0            0        10.3            0             0           0           0              0                  0
8      11      P. Iskander          14            3.3           0.1                      0.5                      0.1             0.9            0.4           0.1             0              0.4                  0.1            46      1              0                 2                   0           0.5                    0                 1                 7       12       5      1            0         6             2               0.83              0.17                  0.50                     0       0           4              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
9      33      B. Ackerman          26           24.0           8.6                      3.2                      2.8             6.0            1.5           0.5           0.3              1.6                  1.2           623    224             90               169                  53           1.3                   54                74                82      156      39     14            9        41            32               0.95              0.34                  0.44                  0.28       2          16              0            3            0        11.5            0           8.0           0           0              0                  0
10     22      L. Santiago          27            9.3           2.3                      2.8                      1.4             4.3            0.4           0.5           0.6              0.4                  1.0           250     61             27                72                  38           0.8                   38                39                76      115      10     14           17        12            27               0.83              1.17                  0.52                  0.63       0          13              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
11     23          T. Pham          25           17.5           8.2                      4.7                      1.8             6.5            1.1           0.5           1.1              2.1                  1.6           438    206             84               153                  55           1.3                   56                45               117      162      27     12           27        52            41               0.52              0.23                  0.29                  0.66       0          24              0            4            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0
12      5      P. Guerrero          29           26.9          20.1                      4.6                      2.0             6.5            2.9           1.7           0.7              3.2                  1.3           779    583            218               519                  42           1.1                   47                57               132      189      84     49           21        92            38               0.91              0.53                  1.29                  0.55       0          58              0            5            0        23.9            0           7.8           0           0              0                  0
13      2  J. Smith-sherry          29           12.3           2.0                      1.0                      0.7             1.7            1.3           0.6           0.1              1.1                  1.0           357     59             23                63                  37           0.9                   40                21                28       49      38     18            3        32            30               1.19              0.56                  0.60                  0.10       1          26              0            0            0           0            0             0           0           0              0                  0


You're correct about the concatenating not working. I copied the wrong version in my answer...

Probably not the cleanest solution, but this seems to do the trick. This format requires a bit more wrangling than just an import in a Pandas DataFrame.
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

test_url = 'https://production.api.maxpreps.com/gatewayweb/react/team-season-player-stats/rollup/v1?teamId=cb3c4816-4749-4381-8c4c-5613ef8c89c9&sportSeasonId=77be7c75-cdf9-483d-867f-ea2af557e731'
url_json = requests.get(url=test_url).json()

df_dict = {}
for group_idx, group in enumerate(url_json['data']['groups']):
    group_dict = {}
    for subgroup in group['subgroups']:
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(subgroup['stats']['rows']):
            row_dict = {}
            for col_idx, col in enumerate(subgroup['stats']['columns']):
                header = col['displayName']
                value = row['columns'][col_idx]['value']
                row_dict[header] = value
            group_dict[row_idx] = row_dict
        df_dict[group_idx] = group_dict

for df in df_dict:
    if df == 0:
        df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_dict[df]).T
    else:
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_dict[df]).T
        try:
            df_out = df_out.merge(df_temp, on=['#', 'Name', 'Games Played'], how='outer')
        except KeyError: # Per 32 stats doesn't include 'Games Played' column
            df_out = df_out.merge(df_temp, on=['#', 'Name'], how='outer')


Hi, it definitely looks a lot more cleaner that way. However, there is a lot of "NaN" and eventually it stops ligning up with all the correct player values (The first half of data is good, then it branches off and becomes incorrect). Is there any cause for this misalignment and NaN values?

So, I wasn't awake enough yet... ;-). I copied the wrong version of my code in the answer. Concatenating didn't work, because not all df's had 15 rows. Merging does work. I do like Chitown88's version with using _DROP as a suffix better than my fix with try/except...
